# Как протестировать WeakReference в потоке?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я хочу разобраться как работает WeakReference на простом примере. Есть подозрения что в моей программе WeakReference в отдельном потоке становится strong ссылкой.

Попытался сделать следующим образом:

```
public class TestWeak {

private static Object object;
private static WeakReference<Object> wr;
private static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Object object4 = object;
            System.out.println("Object4: " + object4);
            Object object5 = wr.get();
            System.out.println("Object5: " + object5);

            System.out.println("Setting object to null");
            object = null;
            System.out.println("Running Garbage Collection...");
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); // run GC to collect the object
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            System.out.println("Setting object4 to null");
            object4 = null;
            System.out.println("Running Garbage Collection...");
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); // run GC to collect the object  
            Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            System.out.println("Setting object5 to null");
            object5 = null;
            System.out.println("Running Garbage Collection...");
            Runtime.getRuntime().gc(); // run GC to collect the object              
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    object = new Object();      
    // Create a new weak reference that refers to the given object and is registered with this queue.
    wr = new WeakReference<Object>(object); // , rq);
    System.out.println("Object: " + object);
    Object object2 = wr.get();
    System.out.println("Object2: " + object2);
    Object object3 = object2;
    System.out.println("Object3: " + object3);      
    // start a new thread that will remove all references of object     
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    service.schedule(runnable, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Wait ....");
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {
        if (wr.get() == null) {
            System.out.println("Reference: " + wr);
            System.out.println("Object is no longer referenced.");
            flag = false;
        }                   
    }
    service.shutdown();     
}
}
```

Console:

```
Object: java.lang.Object@7852e922
Object2: java.lang.Object@7852e922
Object3: java.lang.Object@7852e922
Wait ....
Object4: java.lang.Object@7852e922
Object5: java.lang.Object@7852e922
Setting object to null
Running Garbage Collection...
Setting object4 to null
Running Garbage Collection...
Setting object5 to null
Running Garbage Collection...
Reference: java.lang.ref.WeakReference@3d4eac69
Object is no longer referenced.
```

**Почему GC удаляет объект только после того как object5 (weak ссылка) устанавливается в null ?**

UPDATE:

Если закомментировать эту строку:

```
// object5 = null;
```

Вы никогда не увидите в консоли:

```
Object is no longer referenced.
```

Наши заморские друзья говорят что GC работает как ему вздумается.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784793/java-weakreference-inside-thread

Но на мой взгляд приведенный пример никак не отражается на разной работе GC, а проблема заключается в неправильной работе/использовании WeakReference.

P.S. Так же пробовал параллельно переполнить память. Память переполнил, а в нужную строку в консоли так и не увидел.

Comment: И они правы....

Comment: Возможно! Но вот ответа на вопрос: Почему тогда комментирование всего одной строки в приведенном примере вызывает отказ GC обрабатывать WeakReference? - У них нет!

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код в вопросе и уточните, какую именно строку нужно закомментировать, чтобы вызвать отказ GC обрабатывать WeakReference.

Comment: А вообще, ответ простой: GC работает так как ему вздумается, и вызов `System.gc()` ему не указ. Это лишь "совет" начать сборку мусора, окончательное решение о запуске GC остаётся за JVM. Всегда остаётся шанс того, что вызов `System.gc()` будет проигнорирован.

Comment: Почему минусуют вопрос? Чем он так плох?

Comment: @fori1ton, пример кода добавил. И собственно говоря вопрос не заключается в том чтобы заставить GC работать по моей "указке". Вопрос заключается в том чтобы протестировать на простом примере что WeakReference работает как должен. Мне пока сделать это не удалось.

Comment: Попробуйте нагенерировать много мусора в цикле, чтобы пробудить GC.

Comment: @Nofate, я же написал: "Так же пробовал параллельно переполнить память."

Comment: А правда, почему минусуют? Вопрос не праздный, о деталях работы сборщика мусора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ошибаетесь, считая что `object5` - это слабая ссылка на объект. `object5` - это сильная ссылка. Слабая ссылка в вашей программе только одна - `wr`.

Comment: Да, действительно Вы правы: ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#get() ) Returns: The object to which this reference refers, or null if this reference object has been cleared